# Official definition of System V service management

Tags: systemd, services, system-v

[Several](https://danielmiessler.com/study/the-difference-between-system-v-and-systemd/#:%7E:text=Here%20are%20the%20main%20differences%20between%20the%20two.,much%20more.%20SystemD%20handles%20startup%20processes%20through.service%20files.) [sources](https://fossbytes.com/systemd-vs-sys-v-vs-upstart/) [online](https://www.techtarget.com/searchdatacenter/tip/Master-Linux-service-management-on-System-V-and-systemd) discusses the difference between Linux systemd service management facility and that of System V.

While there's an official website for [systemd](https://systemd.io), I found no official definition for that of System V (I checked SVID issue 2, SVR4's User Manual, Programming Guide, and Sys Admin Guide, and Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard).

To phrase the question to avoid it being closed as a reference request: Is System V service management facility something officially defined or just a set of conventions adopted by the user community?

Comment: Requests for documentation are off-topic for U&L, but sysvinit comes with documentation and man pages.  If you don't want to install sysvinit just to read them, you can find them in the github repo at https://github.com/slicer69/sysvinit - AFAIK, there is no specification document for sysv.  It doesn't really need one - it's not trying to turn linux into a poor imitation of a Mac/Windows hybrid, by borging everything into one do-everything-badly program.

Comment: @cas Fair enough, but I see this sentence in the help center page for topicallity: "The only exception is questions about where to find official documentation (e.g. POSIX specifications)." and if you consider Unix System V documents non-official, then please do close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AT&T System V service management was documented, somewhat succinctly, in the `rc0`, `rc2`, and `rc6` manual pages.

[`rc0` documents the shutdown sequence](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/att/unix/System_V_Release_4_Intel/0139513280_Users_Reference_Manual_System_Administrators_Reference_Manual_Intel_Processors_Commands_m-z_1992.pdf#page=308):

- run files starting with `K` in `/etc/rc0.d`, in ASCII order;
- send `SIGTERM` to all still-running processes other than `rc0` and processes 0 and 1;
- send `SIGKILL` to all still-running processes other than `rc0` and processes 0 and 1;
- unmount all file systems other than `/`.

[`rc2` documents the multi-user startup sequence](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/att/unix/System_V_Release_4_Intel/0139513280_Users_Reference_Manual_System_Administrators_Reference_Manual_Intel_Processors_Commands_m-z_1992.pdf#page=310):

- run files in `/etc/rc.d`, in ASCII order;
- run files starting with `S` in `/etc/rc2.d`, in ASCII order.

[`rc6` documents the reboot sequence](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/att/unix/System_V_Release_4_Intel/0139513280_Users_Reference_Manual_System_Administrators_Reference_Manual_Intel_Processors_Commands_m-z_1992.pdf#page=312):

- build a new kernel if necessary;
- unmount all filesystems.

These manual pages also document how `init` takes care of the rest of the process, following the actions set up in `/etc/inittab`; `init` is also documented [in its own manual page](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/att/unix/System_V_Release_4_Intel/0139513108_Users_Reference_Manual_System_Administrators_Reference_Manual_Intel_Processors_Commands_a-l_1992.pdf#page=560).

Comment: I feel sorry for not noticing them in the first place, but then again, the description didn't contain the keyword "service" which I looked for. (I thought it'd be something like the sophisticated SystemD facility.)

Comment: I found them because I knew what to look for (`rc`) ;-).